# How to toggle AM/PM and MilitaryTime with a button

Tags: javascript

Forgive me if my post is poorly formatted.
I've searched around and cant seem to find a solution to this. I'm building a clock app and I have two buttons, one to toggle 12hr time and one to toggle 24hr time. the 24hr toggle works just fine but I cant toggle back to the 12 hr time.

```js
let isMilitaryTime = false;

let militaryTime = document.getElementById('button24');
militaryTime.addEventListener('click', function () {
    isMilitaryTime = true;
});

let civilTime = document.getElementById('button12');
civilTime.addEventListener('click', function () {
    ismilitaryTime = false;
});

function normalTime() {
    let date = new Date();
    let hour = date.getHours();
    let min = date.getMinutes();
    let sec = date.getSeconds();
    let amPm = hour >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';

    if (isMilitaryTime === true) {
        setInterval(normalTime, 1000);
        document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec;
    } else {
        amPm = hour >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
        hour = hour % 12 || 12;
        setInterval(normalTime, 1000);
        document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec + ' ' + amPm;
    }

    min = min < 10 ? '0' + min : min;
    sec = sec < 10 ? '0' + sec : sec;
}
```

Comment: if you don't know how to do it manually .. why don't you use momen.js ? you could convert with that eaisly.

Comment: Moment is 230kb if you include locals and 60kb if you dont. That's a good reason not to use it unless you are willing to make moment a core piece of your stack. Formatting 24 hour time seems like a bad reason to use moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isMilitaryTime variable in civilTime eventLister was miss-spelled. And better use the interval once, otherwise it was calling exponential amount of setinterval.
Please try this.

```
'''
    var isMilitaryTime = false;
    
    let militaryTime = document.getElementById('button24');
    militaryTime.addEventListener('click', function() { isMilitaryTime = true });
    
    let civilTime = document.getElementById('button12');
    civilTime.addEventListener('click', function() { isMilitaryTime = false });
    
     function normalTime() {
     let date = new Date();
     let hour = date.getHours();
     let min = date.getMinutes();
     let sec = date.getSeconds();
     let amPm = hour >=12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
      min = min < 10 ? '0' + min : min;
      sec = sec < 10 ? '0' + sec : sec;
    
     if(isMilitaryTime === true) {
     document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec;
     } else  {         
       amPm = hour >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'
       hour = hour % 12 || 12;
       
       document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec + ' ' + amPm; 
     }
    }
    setInterval(normalTime, 1000);
```

Instead of using the setInterval its actually better to call the nomalTime function from the eventLister itself like

```
let militaryTime = document.getElementById('button24');
        militaryTime.addEventListener('click', function() { isMilitaryTime = true; 
    normalTime(); });
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to call the `normalTime` method everytime you click the button:

```
let isMilitaryTime = false;

let militaryTime = document.getElementById('button24');
militaryTime.addEventListener('click', function () {
    isMilitaryTime = true;
    normalTime();
});

let civilTime = document.getElementById('button12');
civilTime.addEventListener('click', function () {
    ismilitaryTime = false;
    normalTime();
});
```

Comment: This would cause many many intervals being created. You would have to be sure that you clear the intervals. Also `ismilitaryTime` is misspelled in ops code so this wouldnt directly address his issue.